# Solving $\left(1/3\right)^k n = 1$ for $k$

Tags: logarithms

The goal is to show that $$\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^kn=1 \Rightarrow k = \log_3 n\,.$$

So I started with $\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^kn=1 \Leftrightarrow \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^k=\frac{1}{n}$ in order to use the identity $y=a^x \Leftrightarrow x=\log_a y$, which then yields $$k=\log_{1/3} \frac{1}{n}$$ which using $\log \frac{1}{x}=-\log a$ can be written as $$k = -\log_{1/3} n\,.$$ But that is not
what I wanted to show, as $\log_3 n \neq -\log_{1/3} n$.

I don't know where the mistake is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$-\log_{1/3} n = \frac{\log_{1/3} n}{\log_{1/3}3} = \log_3 n$$

Comment: Thank you! That was fast. I will accept your answer as soon as it will let me.

Comment: Sorry, I've got another question: the identity you used is $\log_b (a)=\frac{\log_c a}{\log_c b}$, right? In your answer, $c=\frac{1}{3}$, but couldn't it be any arbitrary number as $c$ bears no relation to either $a$ or $b$?

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow Yes, but keep in mind that $0<c \neq 1$ for the logarithms to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

$$\left( \frac{1}{3^k}\right)n=1$$

Multiplying $3^k$ on both sides,
$$n=3^k$$

Hence $$k = \log_3 n$$

Comment: Thank you very much. This is even more elegant. I'm afraid I already accepted an answer

Comment: Don't worry about reputations. I just see a question and just lift a few fingersl ;) The other solution teach you why $-\log_{\frac13} n = \log_3 n$.